# How to make multiple reference cells draggable with Indirect and sumif

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a non-continuous range across the same row and same sheet which I would like to sum based on a criteria. Since they are non-continuous I'm using indirect

The issue I'm having is that `H5`, `J5`, `L5`, `N5` and `P5` do not update to H6, J6,L6,N6 and P6. I've about 30 rows looking for aid from one of you geniuses savants, this is way over my IQ.

```
=SUM(SUMIF(INDIRECT({"H5","J5","L5","N5","P5"}),">0"))
```

I'm using excel latest, or whatever desktop version comes with 365

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(F5:Q5,(F5:Q5>0)*(ISODD(COLUMN(F5:Q5))))/(COUNTIFS(F5:Q5,ISEVEN(COLUMN(F5:Q5)),F5:Q5,">0"))

Comment: Do the cells in the interval contain numbers?

Answer (score 1):

SUMPRODUCT, It avoids the volatile INDIRECT and it can be dragged/copied:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(H5:P5,(H5:P5>0)*(ISEVEN(COLUMN(H5:P5))))
```

`(H5:P5>0)*(ISEVEN(COLUMN(H5:P5)))` creates an array of `1` and `0` the same size and shape as the range.  Then SUPRODUCT will multiply the values in the range with the `1` and `0` in that array and return the sum of the values.

Since `1` times any number is that number and `0` times any number is `0` it will only return the values that meet the criteria of being greater that 0 and in the even columns, H,J,L,N, and P.

[image]

---

With Office 365

We can use FILTER to FILTER only the values wanted then sum.  We use LET to limit the duplicated references:

```
=LET(r,H5:P5,SUM(FILTER(r,(r>0)*(ISEVEN(COLUMN(r))))))
```

[image]

---

And then if the `">0"` was a way for SUMIF to be used as an array formula and you do not really need the `>0` criteria then just use SUM() which can use disjointed ranges:

```
=SUM(H5,J5,L5,N5,P5)
```

Comment: Thanks this is brilliant .

Answer (score 0):

Or to get the ">0" test into the more general solution:

```
=SUM((H5>0)*H5,(J5>0)*J5,(L5>0)*L5,(N5>0)*N5,(P5>0)*P5)
```